# Reference Binding to null pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(vector<int>& nums) {
        
        vector<int> cons;
        int count=0;
        int len=nums.size();
        
        if(nums.empty())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {   
              int i=0;
              while(i<len)
             {
                  if(nums[i]==1)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
               {
                  cons.push_back(count);
                  count=0;
                }
              i++;
              }
            int val=*max_element(cons.begin(),cons.end());
            return val;
        }
        
    }
};
```

Why I am getting the above error.

```
Line 788: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_iterator.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_iterator.h:797:16
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Based on the code you've shown, what sticks out to me is that you're using the result of `max_element` without ensuring it is not equal to `cons.end()`.  The vector `cons` can be empty if all values in `nums` are equal to `1`, and that might lead to this sort of runtime error if you have compiled your program with some kind of iterator checking debug option.

Answer (score 0):

This here is causing the problem

```
int val=*max_element(cons.begin(),cons.end());
```

Add this condition to check if `cons` is not empty

```
int val;
     if(cons.size()!=0)
           val=*max_element(cons.begin(),cons.end());
```